# Add data to cell based on other cell values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large group of data with various names and sources, in a large dataframe.

Reproducible data by [Anshul Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12696163/anshul-jain)

```py
First_Name  Last_Name   Source
      Matt      Jones       XX
     James      Smith       YY
     Smith     Weston       AA
    Weston  Supermare       CC
      Matt      Jones       YY
    Weston  Supermare       FF

# copy in with:
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
```

The data looks as follows:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+
| First Name | Last Name | Source |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| Matt       | Jones     | XX     |
| James      | Smith     | YY     |
| Smith      | Weston    | AA     |
| Weston     | Supermare | CC     |
| Matt       | Jones     | YY     |
| Weston     | Supermare | FF     |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

I need it to look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+
| First Name | Last Name | Source |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| Matt       | Jones     | XX, YY |
| James      | Smith     | YY     |
| Smith      | Weston    | AA     |
| Weston     | Supermare | CC, FF |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

I can get the deduplication process to work using:

```
Conn_df = Conn_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['First Name', 'Last Name'])
```

However, before I deduplicate, I need to record all the sources for the same data on the same row.

Comment: That looks nice, but is nearly impossible to get back into a dataframe without manually retyping everything.  Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe by the columns `First Name` and `Last Name` and then apply the `agg` function `join` on the `Source` column.

Use:

```
result = Conn_df.groupby(["First Name", "Last Name"])["Source"].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
  First Name  Last Name  Source
0      James      Smith      YY
1       Matt      Jones  XX, YY
2      Smith     Weston      AA
3     Weston  Supermare  CC, FF
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
print(df.groupby(by=['FirstName', 'LastName']).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)))
FirstName LastName
James     Smith          YY
Matt      Jones      XX, YY
Smith     Weston         AA
Weston    Supermare  CC, FF
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggested solution. The "Source" field gets populated by "None" for every row, using the above.